# How to set example in swagger by xml documentation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

here my model for registration and set comments for example but its still not show in swagger its display somehing like this 
{
userName:"string"
}

instead of 
{
userName:"Jasmin"
}

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the user
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>Jasmin</example>
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// User Contact Number
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>9033156314</example>
        [Required]
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// User Device Id
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>12364457tryhret1223</example>
        [Required]
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// User Device Info
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>Jasmin</example>
        [Required]
        public string DeviceInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

and my method is below

```
/// <summary>
        /// Register User Through Contact Number.
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterViewModel model)
        {

}
```

but example is not shown in swagger

Comment: can you please let us know, version of swashbuckle and is model class is in a separate project ?

Comment: Did you set XML documentation file from properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update for Swashbuckle 4.x, which does support the use of the  tag. (see https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore )

Then my Startup.cs code looks like this

```
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                // Set Title and version from config
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My Title", Version = "1.0", Description = "My Description" });
                // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                // pick comments from classes, include controller comments: another tip from StackOverflow
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
                // enable the annotations on Controller classes [SwaggerTag]
                c.EnableAnnotations();
                // to allow for a header parameter
                c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<example>` XML documentation tag is not utilized by Swashbuckle. You have to use an `IOperationalFilter` to manually add examples, as there's no built-in way. However, someone was nice enough to create a NuGet package that makes it much easier, aptly named [`Swashbuckle.Examples`](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples). For an ASP.NET Core project, you'll actually need the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples` or `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` NuGets, depending on the version of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` you're running.

Comment: Nowdays, Swashbuckle (v6.3.1) shows the `example` tag as well